# Reverse slice/chop of string in Go Template

Tags: go-templates, sprig-template-functions

In gotemplate (sprig), given the following strings:

```
one-use1-dev-01
one-two-use1-dev-01
one-two-three-use1-dev-01
```

I would like to "chop" off `use1-dev-01` and return `one`, `one-two` or `one-two-three`.

`use1-dev-01` will always be three segments, but `dev` could be `stage`, etc (eg, `use1-stage-01`).

What is the simplest way to handle this?  I'm looking at trying to use `regexpReplaceAll` or `regexpSplit` but have been unsuccessful thus far.